# redux-thunk dispatch method fires undefined action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Here is the code I'm playing with

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import axios from 'axios'

const initialState = {
    user: {},
    requesting: false,
    err: null
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'REQ_USER_INIT': return { ...state, requesting: true }
        case 'REQ_USER_DATA': return { ...state, requesting: false, user: action.user }
        case 'REQ_USER_ERR': return { ...state, requesting: false, err: action.err }
    }
    return state;
}

const logger = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
    let previous = JSON.stringify(store.getState())
    next(action)
    console.log(
        'action: ' + JSON.stringify(action) +
        '\n\tprevious: ' + previous +
        '\n\tcurrent: ' + JSON.stringify(store.getState())
    )
}

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(logger, thunk))

store.dispatch((dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'REQ_USER_INIT' })

    // Fake Online REST API for Testing and Prototyping
    // break url to get an error response
    let usersEndpoint = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1'

    axios.get(usersEndpoint)
        .then((response) => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'REQ_USER_DATA',
                user:  {
                    id: response.data.id,
                    username: response.data.username,
                    email: response.data.email,
                }
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'REQ_USER_ERR',
                err: error.message
            })
    })
})
```

I believe it is pretty straightforward, right? I dispatch `REQ_USER_INIT` and then `REQ_USER_DATA` once the response is received. I should log two actions, however I get 3. Second action is `undefined` and I am strugling to figure out what causes it. Is it a bug with **redux-thunk** or am I doing something wrong?

Here is the output from my console:

```
action: {"type":"REQ_USER_INIT"}
·previous: {"user":{},"requesting":false,"err":null}
·current: {"user":{},"requesting":true,"err":null}
action: undefined
·previous: {"user":{},"requesting":false,"err":null}
·current: {"user":{},"requesting":true,"err":null}
action: {"type":"REQ_USER_DATA","user":{"id":1,"username":"Bret","email":"Sincere@april.biz"}}
·previous: {"user":{},"requesting":true,"err":null}
·current: {"user":{"id":1,"username":"Bret","email":"Sincere@april.biz"},"requesting":false,"err":null}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The order of middlewares matters. Try making `logger` last

```
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk, logger))
```

Comment: Thank you! Perfect. Wouldn't come up with that on my own. Would you care to explain it why order matters please?

Comment: "why order matters" imagine there is an array of middlewares `middlewares` and `dispatch` will pass every event to each middleware from left to right. So if you have middleware that transforms action somehow (like thunk does) you do want it to run before logger logs it to console.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you. I am referencing this answer int [github issue](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk/issues/91)